# Why can't I invoke a function directly?

Tags: javascript

I am working through a small exercise from code school and cant figure out why I have to pass the function `buildTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide);` to a variable and then invoke the function on the variable to make this script work.

The code below will not execute (I don't assign the function to a variable):

```
var parkRides = [
    ["Birch Bumpers", 40],
    ["Pines Plunge", 55],
    ["Cedar Coaster", 20],
    ["Ferris Wheel", 90]
];

var fastPassQueue = ["Cedar Coaster", "Pines Plunge", "Birch Bumpers", "Pines Plunge"];

var wantsRide = "Birch Bumpers";

function buildTicket(allRides, passRides, pick) {
    if(passRides[0]==pick){
        var pass = passRides.shift();
        return function(){
            alert("Quick you have a fast pass to "+pass+"!");
        };
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i<allRides.length; i++){
            if(allRides[i][0] == pick){
                return function (){
                    alert("A ticket is printing for "+pick+"!\n"+
                          "Your wait time is about "+allRides[i][1]+" minutes.");
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

buildTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide);
```

But if I add `var ticket = buildTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide);  ticket();` it works properly.   Full code below:

```
var parkRides = [
    ["Birch Bumpers", 40],
    ["Pines Plunge", 55],
    ["Cedar Coaster", 20],
    ["Ferris Wheel", 90]
];

var fastPassQueue = ["Cedar Coaster", "Pines Plunge", "Birch Bumpers", "Pines Plunge"];

var wantsRide = "Birch Bumpers";

function buildTicket(allRides, passRides, pick){
    if(passRides[0]==pick) {
        var pass = passRides.shift();
        return function(){
            alert("Quick you have a fast pass to "+pass+"!");
        };
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i<allRides.length; i++){
            if(allRides[i][0] == pick){
                return function (){
                    alert("A ticket is printing for "+pick+"!\n"+
                          "Your wait time is about "+allRides[i][1]+" minutes.");
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

var ticket = buildTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide);

ticket();
```

Any insight as to why I need to pass the function to a variable and then call the variable would be greatly appreciated.   I am sure I am missing the obvious here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `buildTicket` function returns a function that does not use a parameter.

For instance, in your code, it returns with a function here:

```
 return function(){alert("Quick you have a fast pass to "+pass+"!");
        };
```

You could invoke the returned function immediately with this syntax:

```
buildTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide)();
```

You could also change the `return` lines in `function buildTicket` to immediately alert instead of returning a function, but that could break other uses of `buildTicket` that expect it to return a function thereby delaying that alert to possibly display at a particular point in the code later when it is needed.

Comment: Is there a name for this syntax?

Comment: Much thanks - solves the problem and gives me the reason why. I suspect I could also return the alert directly without the function and achieve the same result with the call buildTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide);

Comment: There are some cute acronyms for the anonymous version that people use to create local scopes, i.e. in a for loop.  IIFE Immediately Invoked Function Expression, etc.

Comment: @JoshKerbel Glad to help. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine!

```
buildTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide)();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the variable ticket(); you are doing one more function call than you would do otherwise.

Basically the first buildTicket call by itself... 
    buildTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide);

looks like...

```
(function buildTicket(allRides, passRides, pick) {
    //... your code here that is returning a function
}(parkRides, fastPassQueue, wantsRide);
```

under the hood, and will return an anonymous function containing an alert that has not been invoked yet. Looking like...

```
(function () {
    //... your code containing an alert
});
```

and since it has not been bound to a variable it is just sitting there unable to be invoked because you have no references to it now.
There are 2 ways around this problem:
 1) you have already figured out which is assigning the anonymous function to a variable and invoking the function using the variable.
 2) Is to immediately invoke the returned function by adding another set of parens.

In the end they both do the same thing and will end up giving you the alert via

```
(function () {
    //... your code containing an alert
})();
```

Also, if all you want is to invoke the alert, you can forget about the extra function statement and the return call and just have

```
function buildTicket(allRides, passRides, pick){
    if(passRides[0]==pick){
        var pass = passRides.shift();
        alert();
    }else {
        for(var i = 0; i<allRides.length; i++){
            if(allRides[i][0] == pick){
                alert();                                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```