# why are nested functions executed when I only invoke it through a variable?

Tags: javascript

why do I have to write a variable, assign a function to it and only after that it works fine. Why?

I have been searching it on Google and found almost the same question here [Why can't I invoke a function directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334231/why-cant-i-invoke-a-function-directly). But the problem is that his code is complex and all people's explanations about his code are based on his one whereas I'm beginner so I don't entirely understand his code, thus explantions too

My code

```
function foo() {
  let a = 10;
  let b = 20;

  function bar() {
    return a + b;
  }

  return bar;
}

foo();
```

But if assign the function to a variable, it works.

```
let x = foo();
x();
```

Comment: `return bar;` will throw a `ReferenceError`... neither of those codes should work

Comment: In the second example you are doing something with the return value of `foo`: `x()` calls the return value as a function. You are not doing that in the first example. This has nothing to do with variables. The equivalent without using `x` would be `foo()();`.

Comment: I think you meant `return boo` - `foo` returns a function, so you need to also invoke the returned function

Comment: You can arrive at the same result from the second example in the first by calling the first example like this `foo()()`.

As the others have mentioned this is because your function `foo` is returning another function. However it looks like you have a reference error there as well, maybe you meant for that function to return `boo` like @ic3b3rg has mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with variables. A variable is just a container for a value. You can easily omit the variable assignment without changing the behavior of your program.

So lets work backwards and remove `x` from your second example:

```
// `x` is the same as `foo()`
// `x()` therefor becomes
foo()()
```

And now you should see the difference:

```
foo()   // first example
// vs
foo()() // second example
```

`foo` *returns a function*. You have to call that function. And you already know that functions are called with `()`. So `foo()()` calls `foo`, and then calls the return value of `foo`.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('inside foo');
  function bar() {
    console.log('inside bar');
  }
  return bar;
}

console.log('foo()');
foo();
console.log('foo()()');
foo()();
```